# Typing the currency symbol for peso in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am aware that pressing and holding "alt", then pressing "8369" on the keypad will give you the Peso currency symbol(₱). However I am not able to create this in my VBA code. Has anyone been able to create this, or a feasible workaround? (▒) this is what I got when trying it here in my question box, the other one above was a cut and paste which will not work in VBA.

Comment: Try `chrw(8369)`

Comment: That didn't work but I tried "[$₱-3409]#.##0,00") in the work sheet which worked but in the code the symbol turned to a (?) mark.

Comment: Based on some quick googling, it appears that the VBA code editor doesn't support Unicode, but rather depends upon the "code page that is used by the Windows system locale as specified in the Region under control panel." ([link](https://www.spreadsheet1.com/how-to-display-foreign-characters-in-vbe.html)). So if you want to display the peso character in your VBA editor, you might need to change your Windows settings (if that's an option).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you pick a font that will display unicode:

```
Sub Peso()
    Dim s As String, r As Range
    Set r = Range("A1")
    s = ChrW(8369)
    With r
        .NumberFormat = s & "#,##0"
        .Font.Name = "Arial Unicode MS"
    End With
End Sub
```

[image]

*(pick thousands and decimal separators to suit your needs)*

Comment: Thanks that works on my sheet results . I'm wondering if there is a way to get it to display aswell in the textbox control. But thank you very much for the sheet solution. much appreciated.

Comment: @WayneSeymour  Thanks for the feedback.......Your follow-on question is **really** interesting.....I suggest you open a new question about displaying unicode in a Form.